# Handling file upload in Sharepoint List with React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint

I am creating a form webpart with react but I am stuck at uploading a file, So I want to upload a file when it hit submit button and that has to create sharepoint list item with attachment file.

[image]

above image is for reference to understand.

Now I am able to create Above two Subjects and comments in sharepoint list but unsure for upload to attach with same list item as `attachments`.

```
<div className={styles.row}>
          <ReactFileReader fileTypes={[".csv", ".xlsx", ".Docx", ".pdf"]} base64={true} handleFiles={this.handleFiles.bind(this)}>
            <button className='btn' value={this.state.UploadedFilesArray.toString()} >Upload</button>
          </ReactFileReader>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.row}>
        <div  >
          <button id="btn_add" className={styles.button} onClick={this.createItem.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
        </div>
```

The above code is for Upload and Submit, As I said I want to attach the attachment when I submit the form.

```
  private createItem(): void {  
    this.setState({  
      status: 'Creating item...',  
      items: []  
    });
    const body: string = JSON.stringify({
      'Title': this.state.subject,
      'Comments': this.state.comments,
    });    
    this.props.spHttpClient.post(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items`,  
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,  
    {  
      headers: {  
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',  
        //"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',  
        'odata-version': ''  
      },
      body: body
    })  
    .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<IListItem> => {  
      return response.json();  
      console.log(response)
    })  
    .then((item: IListItem): void => {  
      this.setState({
        status: `Item '${item.Title}' (ID: ${item.Id}) successfully created`,  
        items: []  
      });  
    }, (error: any): void => {  
      this.setState({  
        status: 'Error while creating the item: ' + error,  
        items: []  
      });  
    });  
  }
```

The above code is for handling the submit, Now can anyone help me creating the handle file function with the functionality that I want to create a sharepoint list item with an attachment when I hit the Submit button. Also with Success or Error message.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this awesome library [PNPJS library](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/attachments/#add-multiple), it will be easy to work with attachments.

- [Use (PnPJS) library with SharePoint Framework web parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-sp-pnp-js-with-spfx-web-parts#run-the-example)
- Add attachments after item created

```js
private handleFiles(f) {
 var filelist = f.fileList;

 var fileInfos: IAttachmentFileInfo[] = [];

 fileInfos.push({
   name: "My file name 1",
   content: "string, blob, or array"
 });

 // loop through files
 for (var i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {

   // get item
   let file: File = filelist.item(i);

   fileInfos.push({
     name: file.name,
     content: file
   });

 }

 this.setState({
   uploadfiles: fileInfos
 });
}
```

```js
private createItem(): void {

  sp.web.lists.getByTitle("mylist").items.add({
    'Title': this.state.subject
  }).then((r: IItemAddResult) => {
    r.item.attachmentFiles.addMultiple(this.state.uploadfiles);
  }).then(e => {
    console.log("successfully created");
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log("Error while creating the item" + e)
  });
}
```

For more details, please refer to below demo:
[SharedSPFx](https://github.com/kongmengfei/SharedSPFx/blob/master/pnpjsuploadfiles/src/webparts/pnpjsuploadfiles/components/Pnpjsuploadfiles.tsx)