# How to upload multiple files to an SP list item as attachments

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am creating an SP webpart using SPFX.
The webpart needs to be able to upload multiple files either using one button or several buttons (one for each file).

I am trying to use this:
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/attachments/#add-multiple

But it doesn't show how to use it with React states. You see, I want to be able to save the file upload into state, so it can then be submitted using a button. That's when it is attached to the list item in SP.
I then want the webpart to be able to display the attached item when the user clicks back on this item. This is why I need to use state.

I have read this:
[React SPFx - Adding files to SharePoint list field using PnPjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202602/react-spfx-adding-files-to-sharepoint-list-field-using-pnpjs)

and this:
[Handling file upload in Sharepoint List with React form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162547/handling-file-upload-in-sharepoint-list-with-react-form)

But they are not clear.

Can someone provide an example of how to use the pnpjs attachments with a React component class using state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test code for your reference:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import styles from './NewReactSpfx.module.scss';
    import { INewReactSpfxProps } from './INewReactSpfxProps';
    import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
    import { Web } from "sp-pnp-js";
    import IAttachmentInfo from "sp-pnp-js";
    export default class NewReactSpfx extends React.Component<INewReactSpfxProps, any> {
      public constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {     
          fileInfos: null
        };
      }
      public render(): React.ReactElement<INewReactSpfxProps> {
        return (
          <div className={styles.newReactSpfx}>
            <div className={styles.container}>
              <div className={styles.row}>
                <div className={styles.column}>
                  <span className={styles.title}>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
                  <p className={styles.subTitle}>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
                  <p className={styles.description}>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
                  <a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" className={styles.button}>
                    <span className={styles.label}>Learn more</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <input type="file" multiple={true} id="file" onChange={this.addFile.bind(this)} />
                <input type="button" value="submit" onClick={this.upload.bind(this)} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
      private addFile(event) {
        //let resultFile = document.getElementById('file');
        let resultFile = event.target.files;
        console.log(resultFile);
        let fileInfos = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < resultFile.length; i++) {
          var fileName = resultFile[i].name;
          console.log(fileName);
          var file = resultFile[i];
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = (function(file) {
             return function(e) {
                  //Push the converted file into array
                   fileInfos.push({
                      "name": file.name,
                      "content": e.target.result
                      });
                    }
             })(file);
          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
        this.setState({fileInfos});
        console.log(fileInfos)
      }
      private upload() {
    
    
        let {fileInfos}=this.state;
    
        
        console.log(this.props)
        let web = new Web(this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
        web.lists.getByTitle("testn").items.getById(2).attachmentFiles.addMultiple(fileInfos);
      }
    }
```

You could get full project here:

https://github.com/Amos-IT/SharePoint-FrameWork-Demos/tree/master/NewReactSPFX

**Updated:**

```
private _onSubmit = (ev) => {
    this.setState({
      FormStatus: 'Submitted',
    }, () => {
      sp.web.lists.getByTitle("PanelMeetings").items.add({
        Title: this.state.Title,
        StartDate: this.state.PanelStartDate,

      }).then(r=>{
        r.item.attachmentFiles.add(this.state.fileInfos)
      });
    });
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the imported Web. I'm using @pnp/sp

Comment: You could try use sp.pnp.js,they are almost same.npm i sp-pnp-js

Comment: Will try that. Also At the end of the code, you reference getById(2), should  that be something different to 2?

Comment: I mean shouldn't it reference the array of selected files?

Comment: It is the item id which you want to upload attachments.

Comment: Can you update your answer to put the upload in a .then because I'm trying to figure out how to upload the file to the item Id but I can't get the Id unless I drop a .then. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: How do you  get  the id?You could call upload function in then method body directly,just add a id parameter in upload.

Comment: I'm not getting the id because the item needs to be submitted to the list first. How would I get the id? Using a .then?

Comment: Please share a code demo on what you want,so I could update it directly.

Comment: https://codepen.io/tom-pipkin/pen/wvGKogR
Sorry I can't be more precise with this codepen, I want to be able to get the id on a newly submitted item, then use that Id to upload the attached files to that item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219599/discussion-between-tom-and-amos-msft).